# Django : Storing an array of strings ( filepaths) in a model field in sqlite3

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I am trying to store an array of image paths (created randomly initially) to be retrieved later as it is and then pass it to an html template.
I have tried using the Arrayfield option given in a lot of answers but I keep gettings errors because probably I am not using postgresql :

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
```

```
lst=ArrayField(
        models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True),
        size=5,
        default=list,
        null=True
    )
```

**errors**

```
from psycopg2.extras import DateRange, DateTimeTZRange, NumericRange
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ArrayField only if your database is Postgresql. Django's default db (sqlite) does not support ArrayField.

Comment: Is there any way to have an arrayfield type field for models stored in sqlite?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but you can try storing them in a CharField by converting the list to a string  (",".join(my_list)) and back to a string while reading (my_model.list.split(","))